# How to stop ChartJS / react-chartjs-2 from re-rendering new lines on plot

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

In my React App, I am adding new dataset lines to a chart. Here is the behavior I am encountering:

- On App start, a chart renders with a single line [desirable]
- When I mousedown on the chart, a **second line** appears on the screen [desirable]
- When I mousedown the second time on the chart, a third line appears on the screen [desirable]

  - At the same time, the **second line** disappears and re-appears on the screen (re-renders?) [**undesirable**]

How can I make it so that the second time I mouse down on the chart, the **second line** doesn't re-render?

Below is a shortened version of the code.
I have also created a [codesandbox environment](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/interesting-shape-fzp4dk) for reproducibility.

The magic is happening at `useEffect(() => { ... }`.
This is where I add an event listener to update `chartData` when the chart canvas is clicked on.

```js
const chartOptions = {
  showLine: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false,
    },
  },
};

function defaultChartData() {
  return {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [
          { x: 1, y: 1 },
          { x: 10, y: 10 },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };
}

export default function App() {
  const chartRef = useRef(null);
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState(defaultChartData());

  // Effects on mouse down
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleMouseDown(e) {
      setChartData((prevChartData) => {
        const newLine = {};
        if (prevChartData.datasets.length == 1) {
          newLine.data = [
            { x: 3, y: 2 },
            { x: 3, y: 7 },
          ];
        } else {
          newLine.data = [
            { x: 5, y: 2 },
            { x: 5, y: 7 },
          ];
        }
        return {
          ...prevChartData,
          datasets: [...prevChartData.datasets, newLine],
        };
      });
    }
    if (chartRef && chartRef.current) {
      const canvas = chartRef.current.canvas;
      canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
      return () => {
        canvas.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
      };
    }
  }, [chartRef]);

  return <Scatter ref={chartRef} options={chartOptions} data={chartData} />;
}
```

Thank you!